# Copying from Dropbox to UNIX machine using rsync or similar?

Tags: unix, dropbox, rsync

Is there any way I can copy data directly from the Dropbox servers to a UNIX server, without being root or having Dropbox software installed there?

Something like:

```
rsync -aP myusername@dropbox.com:somepath/ .
```

(The reason for wanting to do this is that the transfer speed between the UNIX server and the Dropbox server would be much faster since they are both on the backbone, than between my local machine and the UNIX server, which have a home broadband connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you have SSH access to the Dropbox server. Think about it, that would mean the Dropbox server would have thousands if not millions of SSH accounts, just in the chance that a user would use it. Additionally, a default Unix user has access to read so much of the Unix OS and restricting it to just a few commands is somewhat of a big deal. Imagine if your Unix user was somehow able to see the data of another Unix user including their Dropbox data. Good idea though.

Edit: capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wget to download the file from dropbox to the Server from the command line. some thing like

```
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12345678/largefile.zip
```

If you are on a slow link and the download cuts off before all of the file is downloaded, you can resume download from wherever it stopped, by using the -c option with wget. Just do:

```
wget -c http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12345678/largefile.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rclone https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli/issues/60#issuecomment-497713363

install

```
$ curl -OJN https://downloads.rclone.org/rclone-current-linux-amd64.zip
$ unzip rclone-current-linux-amd64.zip
$ cp rclone-v1.47.0-linux-amd64/rclone ~/bin/
```

config https://rclone.org/dropbox/

```
$ rclone config
2019/05/31 15:00:07 NOTICE: Config file "/home/roman/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" not found - using defaults
No remotes found - make a new one
n) New remote
s) Set configuration password
q) Quit config
n/s/q> n
name> dropbox
Type of storage to configure.
Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
Choose a number from below, or type in your own value
 1 / A stackable unification remote, which can appear to merge the contents of several remotes
   \ "union"
 2 / Alias for a existing remote
   \ "alias"
 3 / Amazon Drive
   \ "amazon cloud drive"
 4 / Amazon S3 Compliant Storage Provider (AWS, Alibaba, Ceph, Digital Ocean, Dreamhost, IBM COS, Minio, etc)
   \ "s3"
 5 / Backblaze B2
   \ "b2"
 6 / Box
   \ "box"
 7 / Cache a remote
   \ "cache"
 8 / Dropbox
   \ "dropbox"
 9 / Encrypt/Decrypt a remote
   \ "crypt"
10 / FTP Connection
   \ "ftp"
11 / Google Cloud Storage (this is not Google Drive)
   \ "google cloud storage"
12 / Google Drive
   \ "drive"
13 / Hubic
   \ "hubic"
14 / JottaCloud
   \ "jottacloud"
15 / Koofr
   \ "koofr"
16 / Local Disk
   \ "local"
17 / Mega
   \ "mega"
18 / Microsoft Azure Blob Storage
   \ "azureblob"
19 / Microsoft OneDrive
   \ "onedrive"
20 / OpenDrive
   \ "opendrive"
21 / Openstack Swift (Rackspace Cloud Files, Memset Memstore, OVH)
   \ "swift"
22 / Pcloud
   \ "pcloud"
23 / QingCloud Object Storage
   \ "qingstor"
24 / SSH/SFTP Connection
   \ "sftp"
25 / Webdav
   \ "webdav"
26 / Yandex Disk
   \ "yandex"
27 / http Connection
   \ "http"
Storage> 8
** See help for dropbox backend at: https://rclone.org/dropbox/ **

Dropbox App Client Id
Leave blank normally.
Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
client_id>
Dropbox App Client Secret
Leave blank normally.
Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
client_secret>
Edit advanced config? (y/n)
y) Yes
n) No
y/n> n
Remote config
Use auto config?
 * Say Y if not sure
 * Say N if you are working on a remote or headless machine
y) Yes
n) No
y/n>
y/n> y
If your browser doesn't open automatically go to the following link: http://127.0.0.1:53682/auth
Log in and authorize rclone for access
Waiting for code...
Got code
--------------------
[dropbox]
type = dropbox
token = {"access_token":"<token>","token_type":"bearer","expiry":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
--------------------
y) Yes this is OK
e) Edit this remote
d) Delete this remote
y/e/d> y
Current remotes:

Name                 Type
====                 ====
dropbox              dropbox

e) Edit existing remote
n) New remote
d) Delete remote
r) Rename remote
c) Copy remote
s) Set configuration password
q) Quit config
e/n/d/r/c/s/q> q
```

copy all files from dropbox https://rclone.org/docs/

```
$ rclone copy --dry-run dropbox:/ .
$ rclone copy dropbox:/ .
```